# Research groups in celestial mechanics

Tags: celestial-mechanics

This Exchange may not be the right place to to ask this question, but I would like to know prominent research groups working in celestial mechanics. Although I'm interested in celestial mechanics, since my background is mathematics, I don't know which university has good research groups in celestial mechanics (preferably of math flavor).

I would appreciate any information. Thank you.

Comment: Did you do any research of your own before asking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.